# Overlapping hover decoration

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Given the following images, I'm really not sure how best to approach this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I mean I could make a sprite image and position each link/icon absolute so that when the hover state occurs they don't push each other. However the problem is the clickable area will grow with the hover state thereby overlapping the other buttons and making them hard to click.

Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

**My solution thanks to @ioannis-karadimas**

http://codepen.io/trev/pen/overlapping-hover-states/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there 's no movement involved, there is no reason why you cannot separate the trigger area from the images themselves. Make all triggers invisible divs floating above the graphics, and the clickable area will stay constant and predictable. Changes in the graphics, like overlaying an image with another or changing a sprite's placement need not be related to the clickable area at all.

To help you in the initial positioning and debugging of it, you could initially place a border around each layer, then position them above the graphics. When you are done, remove the border and make the layers transparent filling them with a fully transparent GIF.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried but I think it should work.

```
.button:hover:after {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px; // button's width / 2
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image:url('cross.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an absolutely positioned elments (or, pseudo-elements) inside the icon containers and show them on mouse over. Thus, it won't affect the hover area.

Here's the example with pseudo-elements, but in case you need support for IE < 8, you can just add normal ones:

http://jsfiddle.net/bFVx8/